# CloudFront policy to invalidate only specific distrubution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-iam

I'm using S3 bucket to store files and CloudFront to distribute them. I have a tool that handles synchronization automatically and it works great.

However, I want to be able to also create CloudFront invalidations programmatically. What statement do I need to add to the tool's policy in order to allow creating invalidation only for this specific distribution?

Right now, I have this statement:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
}
```

But, as you can see, it allows to create invalidations for any distribution in account.

I've tried to use these values for `Resource` property, but for some reason the tool gave me an error, saying that access is denied:

- `arn:aws:cloudfront::12345678:distribution/ABCDEFG`
- `arn:aws:cloudfront:::distribution/ABCDEFG`

**What do I need to specify in `Resource` property in order to allow creation of invalidation only for the specific distribution?**

Its ARN is `arn:aws:cloudfront::12345678:distribution/ABCDEFG` for example.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Update:** As of 2021, the `cloudfront:CreateInvalidation` action supports resource-level permissions and can be used to allow invalidating only a specific distribution. See @GraphicalDot's answer below. Original answer — as of 2017 — below.

The `cloudfront:CreateInvalidation` command does not support resource-level permissions. For this reason, only `*` is supported. Thus, it is not possible to restrict a user/role to only be able to invalidate a specific distribution.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cf-api-permissions-ref.html

Comment: Thanks. This explains why it's not working. I was looking for such a table, but wasn't been able to find one or interpret the value myself.

Comment: This saved hours. Thanks!

Comment: having the same issue, but I still believe it is possible to restrict distribution where role has permission to invalidate a cache. please kindly check this tutorial https://blog.zoph.me/cloud/Jekyll-Pipeline-CBCD/

Comment: Hmm. seems like @matt-houser is right. Role settings UI has following warning: "The actions in your policy do not support resource-level permissions and require you to choose All resources". Action in my settings is "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"

Comment: This is not the case anymore. It is actually possible to set the rights on resource level now! See the answer below by @GraphicalDot.

Answer (score 24):

Now CloudFront supports distribution level permissions with IAM policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution",
                "cloudfront:DeleteDistribution",
                "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudfront::<account_id>:distribution/<distribution_id>"
        }
    ]
}
```

More details here: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/access-control-overview.html